# I can't use pyautogui

Tags: python, module, pip, pyautogui

I am trying to download pyautogui in python. I use pip for that and I write pip install pyautogui. Then cmd download it but when I try to import it in pycharm I cannot find it. I delete pyautogui using with pip and then I download it again but it doesn't work. I cannot find it in module library but when I write list pip in cmd it shown. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which python version are you using. As the [PyAutoGUI documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) says, As of October 2019, the Pillow module doesn’t support Python 3.8. PyAutoGUI currently depends on this module for its screenshot capabilities.

On Windows, you can use the `py.exe` program to run the latest version of Python:

```
py -m pip install pyautogui
```

If you have multiple versions of Python installed, you can select which one with a command-line argument to `py`. For example, for Python 3.8, run:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install pyautogui
```

(This is the same as running `pip install pyautogui`.)

Comment: I am using Python version 3.7.4 and I tried to run py -m pip install pyautogui but it return invalid syntax error at p of pip

Comment: Did you try importing pyautogui in the command-line instead of PyCharm?

Comment: Yes it works in command-line

Comment: but still don't work in pycharm

Comment: Then the problem with the PyCharm Interpreter. 
Go to File -> Setting -> Project Interpreter and create a new virtual interpreter and add the pyautogui there.

Comment: There is no pyautogui in add list and I cannot find new virtual interpreter part. I went to Project Interpreter there is a list in there and there is a + button and I click it even there there is no any pyautogui or PyAutoGUI